# creating a matrix which its odd rows are shifted by 0.5

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I want to create a 10*10 matrix in R, which in odd rows are shifted by +0.5 as follow:

| 1.5 | 2.5 | 3.5 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | ... |
| 1.5 | 2.5 | 3.5 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have tried :

```
x <- seq(1, 10, by=1)
y <- seq(1.5, 10.5, by=1)
mat <- rbind(x, y)
```

but I got a matrix with two rows.and I think there should be a better way to create "y" vector .

how can I do that and what is the most efficient way ?

Comment: It is not clear to me, what values you want to have in the other 8 rows? Could you expand your table with some more rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vector recycling :

```
mat <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 10, nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE)
mat[c(TRUE, FALSE), ] <- mat[c(TRUE, FALSE), ] + 0.5
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5  10.5
# [2,]  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
# [3,]  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5  10.5
# [4,]  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
# [5,]  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5  10.5
# [6,]  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
# [7,]  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5  10.5
# [8,]  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
# [9,]  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5  10.5
#[10,]  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
```